# Google Sheets - Count how many Rows match these conditions

Tags: google-sheets

I got an issue with Queries in Google Sheets.

I have these 3 Columns:

[image]

I would like to COUNT how many Rows have "A" in the first column and the SUM of B and C is more than 2.

This is the Query I tried:

```
=QUERY(Sheet5!A1:C7,"select COUNT(A) where A='A' and B+C>1 LABEL COUNT(A) ''", 1)
```

(I used `LABEL COUNT(A) ''` just to remove the header, the result doesn't change without it)

What am i doing wrong?

By using this Query, I get **1** as result (and it should be 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=QUERY(Sheet5!A1:C7,"select COUNT(A) where A='A' and B+C>1 LABEL COUNT(A) ''", 0)
```

Comment: Give some explanation with your code please.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=QUERY(Sheet5!A1:C7,"select COUNT(A) where A='A' and B=1 and C=1 LABEL COUNT(A) ''", 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work, the result is still 1.

Comment: I have added a screenshot to show you the result!

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTIF(FILTER(A:C,A:A="A",B:B+C:C>1),"<>")/3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `COUNTIFS` and specify the conditions and the ranges for which they are applied:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A7, "=A", B1:B7, ">0", C1:C7, ">0")
```

**Result**

[image: after applying the formula]

#### Reference

- [COUNTIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550).